# Issue implementing public interface in C#

Tags: c#, interface

C# class libary - targetting .NET2 framework.

I'm trying to implement a public interface (exposed from a second referenced assembly) in a small class. The interface has only 3 methods: one is fine, but for some reason I can't implement the other two of them without the compiler complaining for each one that:

- my class "does not implement InterFaceName.MethodName"
- "InterFaceName.MethodName in explicit interface declaration is not a member of interface".

The only difference between the one method which compiles and the other two is that the problem methods each have a parameter which is an Office Interop (Word) type. The other parameters are either bool or members of other public interfaces.

I can add my class definition here if it helps, but I would need to do some paraphrasing since I'm not the "owner" of the other assembly (it is a commercial product) and I'm not sure how they'd feel about me "exposing" it...

That's kind of vague I know, but I'm hoping someone's run into this kind of error before.

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Can you post the definition of the the interface you are trying to implement.

Comment: If the actual code is sensitive, create a minimum reproduction of the problem and post that.

Comment: I think you can expose the interface with no problem. Without seeing the code its much harder to think on a solution.

Comment: Have you tried decompiling the assembly that defines the interface? Doing so may yield some answers and/or clues.

Comment: @Paul - I've used Reflector to look at the interface definition in the referenced assembly: there's nothing in there which stands out (to me at least).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can often happen if the referenced assembly is built against a different version of the Office Interop assemblies.

As a result, even though visibly the parameters declared for "MethodName" may appear to match the interface from the referenced assembly, since the assembly versions are different, the method declaration does not actually match the decleration from the referenced assembly.

Double check you are using the exact same version of the interop assemblies.

Comment: That was it!  Thanks for the suggestion Pete - now compiles with no issues.